# minimum iterations neural network needs for XOR

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

what's the minimum number of exposures to the training set that a standard backprop needs to solve the xor problem? does another type of neural net solve it faster?

what's the best setup (number of hidden layer nodes, learning rate)?

thanks!

Comment: With a good initialization you don't need to train. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the network layout, the learning rate, and regularization parameters if you use them.

You might also get lucky or unlucky with the initial weights of your network, since in a backpropagation network they should be initialized randomly. However the chance of accidentally starting close to a local minimum is small.

For the XOR function, a single hidden layer with 2 nodes should be enough.

A bias node should not be needed. Regularization should also not be needed, because overfitting is not usually a problem for the XOR function.
Regarding learning rate, off the top of my head 0.05 is good, but I have no solid evidence for that. Experiment a little to see if you can find a better value.

The subject is discussed very intuitively in the Coursera "Machine Learning" course. You may want to check the videos on their [Preview](https://class.coursera.org/ml/lecture/preview) site. Look for the "Neural Networks: Learning (Week 5)" section on that page.

Comment: nice answer like +1. would you please also check my question here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86000/one-example-in-classification-using-neural-networks